# ASP.Net Live Editing DLLs for Debugging without killing the session

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to improve our productivity. We have a massive application that takes a long time to rebuild.

This means our change, debug, fix cycle is too long and killing our team performance.

I'm trying to figure out how to live edit dlls without logging in and out of the application.

There is an IIS setting called fcnMode="Disabled" which prevents the session being lost when you publish a new version of a dll. However this simply ignores the changes. Although working on .net applications for many years, I've never had this issue because I've never worked on such a massive application.

There are several other ideas I've had to improve our productivity.

- Simple autologin to speed up rebooting
- Gulp file to live publish javascript changes to improve client side debugging performance
- Change application to run in 64 bit (many dlls to reconfigure so not as easy as it sounds). This will prevent outofmemory exceptions in IIS Express (I hope!).

Please let me know if you have any ideas or can share similar experiences. It may be that I have to settle for logging in and out of the application to refresh the changes but I feel with so many devs working on our project this is at least worth investigating.

Comment: is the app split into multiple Visual Studio projects (and thus produces multiple DLLs? If there are no changes to a project, then as I'm sure you know, you don't generally need to rebuild it, unless a DLL it depends on has also changed. So you don't have to re-build your whole solution every time you correct a typo.

Comment: Yes you are right many dlls. Sure you can a single dll but that tends to cause memory issues. That's why I'd like to use 64 bit. I tried using xcopy in post build to move the compiled dll to the website bin folder which works but blows up the session or as I said you can disable fcnmode which just ignores the changes. I guess this may be a stupid question or may be impossible but I'm looking for someone with better understanding of how the .net process works to prove it.

Comment: Managed to get 64 bit IIS Express working. Turns out there was a third party 32bit dll being consumed